# Where is the recently closed tabs stored on chrome for windows?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Where does chrome store the recently closed tabs on windows 10? I have managed to pause **history** but not the recently closed tabs. I've also marked the History-logs file as read only, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats wrong with using incognito mode.